# Twitter bootstrap collapse issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap responsive css in my web application.This is used in HTML Template with MustacheJS I have "collapse" and that is not working properly in IE-9
This is the code

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#divInsurerList" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne{{_id}}">
    <span rel="tooltip" title="DELETE"><label id="insDeleteView" class="icon-trash"></label></span>
    <span rel="tooltip" title="EDIT"><label id="insUpdateView" class="icon-edit"></label></span>

            <divclass="" style="display: table-cell">{{Name}}</div>
</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne{{_id}}" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
<div class="accordion-inner">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">Name</div>
            {{#isEdit}}<div class="span8"><input id="Name" class="span12" type="text" value="   {{Name}}" /><label id="updateins"></label></div>  <div class="span1"><sup style="color: #a5072e"><b>*</b></sup></div><br />{{/isEdit}}
            {{^isEdit}}<div class="name span9">{{Name}}</div>
        <br />{{/isEdit}}
    </div>
    {{#isEdit}}<button id="insSaveView" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>&nbsp;
    <button id="insCancel" class="btn">Cancel</button>{{/isEdit}}
</div>
</div>
```

There is a **DELETE** and **EDIT** icon in `<div class="accordion-heading">` on click of each of these icon,either a deleteTemplate or an editTemplate are supposed lo load and accordion expands.
so that  `<div id="collapseOne{{_id}}" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">`
becomes  `<div id="collapseOne{{_id}}" class="accordion-body in collapse" style="height: auto; ">`
(class "in" and height:auto) this is working fine in chrome and firefox, issue is in IE.
**That is on clicking EDIT icon content in accordion is not "opening"**
Collapse was initially broken in IE which i fixed by modifying bootstrap Css as shown

```
.collapse {
position: relative;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
//overflow: visible \9;
-webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
   -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
      transition: height 0.35s ease;
}
```

Can anyone say why accordion is not working on "click" of EDIT icon?

Comment: On the Bootstrap website is there an example of this on a page and does that example work in IE9?

Comment: Which document mode/browser mode is being used? Open the Developer Tools (press F12) to find out.

Comment: @thirtydot  document mode/browser mode  is IE/9(as shown in Developer Tools)

Comment: I think it's going to be difficult for anyone to help you without a demo to look at. Can you link to a live site, or make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: @BillyMoat The example on bootstrap page works fine if this line is commented   //overflow: visible \9; (**class collapse in bootstrap.css**) otherwise collapse appears broken in IE9

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe // comments work in CSS. Use /* comment */