# Creating Accordion Table with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table that's populated from a database which has lots of columns (around 30). A solution someone thought of was to create an accordion out the table, where each row is clickable and will accordion downwards with the rest of the columns worth of information. I am having trouble getting Bootstrap to do this properly for me.

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable">
            <td>Some Stuff</td>
            <td>Some more stuff</td>
            <td>And some more</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="accordion" class="collapse">Hidden by default</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb7wy/1/), this functionality is not working. Im not really sure what's wrong, and Bootstrap's docs don't go into much detail on collapsing.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This seems to be already asked before:

This might help:

[Twitter Bootstrap Use collapse.js on table cells [Almost Done]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389775/twitter-bootstrap-use-collapse-js-on-table-cells-almost-done)

UPDATE:

Your fiddle wasn't loading jQuery, so anything worked.

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable">
        <td>Some Stuff</td>
        <td>Some more stuff</td>
        <td>And some more</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="accordion" class="collapse">Hidden by default</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Try this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nb7wy/2/

I also added `colspan='2'` to the details row. But it's essentially your fiddle with jQuery loaded (in frameworks in the left column)

Comment: Heh that's one the resources I used to get me this far. It's over a year old, and did not work for me so I figured a new thread is in order.

Comment: Your edit still does not work. It looks like the hidden row is there, but clicking does not expand or collapse.

Comment: It works for me... this is strange :S do you click on the visible row (some stuf...) and it doesn't shows the hidden one? What browser do you use?

Comment: Yup, clicking on visible row. Hidden row is like half there (need to adjust padding probably). I am on IE9, unfortunately that's the targetted browser. It is Bootstrap 3.x, also.

Comment: So i think that the problem is related to IE9. Could you try it with some other browsers like chrome of firefox, to make sure that is the problem?

Comment: I would if I could. Not allowed to install any without permission. What's weird, is that this works: http://jsfiddle.net/whytheday/2Dj7Y/11/ at least through jsfiddle. It is Bootstrap v2.x, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510840/twitter-bootstrap-collapse-issue-in-internet-explorer maybe this works!

Comment: EDIT: This actually might work. Just removed all but one row and I see it working.

Comment: how can we do this in Loops ?

Comment: I wanted different hidden data for each row so I added a count to the #accordian target for each row. Works great! Thanks for the code. So much simpler than bootstrap-table.com code.

Answer (score 41):

For anyone who came here looking for how to get the true accordion effect and only allow one row to be expanded at a time, you can add an event handler for show.bs.collapse like so:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

I modified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864694/4186945) example to do so here: http://jsfiddle.net/QLfMU/116/

Comment: you can do this withouts js, by adding ```data-target``` to all ```.collapse``` elements, example ```<div id="demo2" class="collapse" data-target=".table">Demo2</div>```

Answer (score 13):

In the accepted answer you get annoying spacing between the visible rows when the expandable row is hidden. You can get rid of that by adding this to css:

```
.collapse-row.collapsed + tr {
     display: none;
}
```

'+' is [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), so if you want your expandable row to be the next row, this selects the next tr following tr named collapse-row.

Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nb7wy/2372/

Comment: how to do that in Loop? I'm getting an issue with angular loops

Comment: i like this, doesn't need any JS

Comment: This breaks the hiding animation though. Any way to avoid that?