# Creating Accordion Table with Materializecss

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am attempting in vain to recreate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148631/creating-accordion-table-with-bootstrap) except using materalize css to do so.

[Materalizecss Collapsible](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) looks like it should be easy to implement into a table format although I'm not sure how to do it.

If anyone could provide a work example that would be great.

I've attempted to create a very small [Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/dqnsq76n/) to no avail also.

```
<table class="striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">Name</th>
      <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <tr class="collapsible-header">
      <td>Alvin</td>
      <td>Eclair</td>
      <td>$0.87</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapsible-body">
      <td>Alan</td>
      <td>Jellybean</td>
      <td>$3.76</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but in-case anyone else is wondering.

MaterializeCSS 0.97.7 is looking for:

```
(> li > .collapsible-header)
(> li > .collapsible-body)
```

Not sure how to get the headers to line up but here's what I did for my test: https://jsfiddle.net/1cq8wd4p/