# Creating a dynamically generated accordion with bootstrap 4 with onclick AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, html, json, bootstrap-4, dynamically-generated

Ok, so there are a few parts to what I'm trying to do.  I've gotten my JSON data returned to me, and now I need to make a Bootstrap accordion table with each main row containing four 'table cells' or an equivalent thereof, but when I click on that row, I want to display the rest of the information in the accordion directly underneath the row.  However, I'm not quite sure how to dynamically generate a multi-row accordion table with an unknown number of rows, since this is more about creating a table with an actual `<tbody>` tag unlike [my last terrible attempt at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148631/creating-accordion-table-with-bootstrap).  Any help here?  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148631/creating-accordion-table-with-bootstrap) but it didn't seem applicable to my needs at all.  Here's something that's ALMOST there, but it needs to be able to use correctly aligned table rows and cells in the places where the text is on the main rows.

https://codepen.io/Sp00ky/pen/akVkyV

I need to be able to have nicely aligned rows and columns...this should look like a table with a dropdown panel for every row when finished.

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response))).each(function() {
        var foNum = this['Factory Order#'];
        var pO = this['PO#'];
        var status = this['Status'];
        var shipDate = this['Ship Date'];
        var dat = '{\"username\":' + "\"" + username + "\"}";        
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + "portal/getdata/orders/" + foNum,
            method: 'POST',
            cors: true,
            data: dat,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                $('.orders').append(
                    '<div class="panel panel-default">'+
                        '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading_'+index+'">'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_'+index+'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_'+index+'">'+
                                '<td>' + foNum + '</td><td>' + pO  + '</td><td>' + status + '</td><td>' + shipDate + '</td>' +
                            '</a>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div id="collapse_'+index+'" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading_'+index+'">'+
                        '<div class="panel-body">'+
                            'blahblah'+ //PUT DETAILS HERE
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'
                );
                index+=1;
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Error: Could not get details.");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: That isn't meeting the requirements of the question.  This is not a simple accordion.  This has to be perfectly aligned table cells.

Comment: *sigh* yes it does, you're just too lazy to adapt it to your needs. Looks at this: https://jsfiddle.net/z88vuck9/

Comment: @AussieJoe where the heck is that index variable coming from?  This is why i don't understand fiddles.  Like...where is it being defined?

Comment: look in the foreach declaration. it's the second parameter (output). It technically is the index output. Look at the official documentation, index is an optional parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @AussieJoe the other thing is, this fiddle needs hella modification to actually be appended to look like a table right?  I need `<th>` elements and this stuff needs to line up.  I'l add more code...